# why TweenLite.delayedCall function (function, count) just repeated 4 times and then stops

Tags: html, gsap

i don't know why `TweenLite.delayedCall` function (function, count) just repeated 4 times and then stops?

```
function test1()
{
    console.log('1');
    TweenLite.delayedCall(2, test2);
}

function test2()
{
    console.log('2');
    TweenLite.delayedCall(2, test3);
}

function test3()
{
    console.log('3');
    TweenLite.delayedCall(2, test4);
}

function test4()
{
    console.log('4');
    TweenLite.delayedCall(2, test1);
}
```

i don't know why `TweenLite.delayedCall` function (function, count) just repeated 4 times and then stops?

thanks any answer from you!

Comment: so what is the output being printed from `console.log()` ? and how do you call the function in the beginning?

Comment: I just want to repeat the function, the function has moi own work.

but mostly it's just the right thing to do and not repeat 4 more times.

console.log () the result is: 1,2,3,4,1 and not continue.

I did a lot of ways, but do not understand why it can not continue.

are looking forward to help.

Comment: That code works fine :- http://jsfiddle.net/net_uk_sweet/ryanydkv/

Comment: Thanks sweet. I have found my error code is wrong. please close the thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function test1()
{
    console.log('1');
    TweenMax.delayedCall(2, test2);
}

function test2()
{
    console.log('2');
    TweenMax.delayedCall(2, test3);
}

function test3()
{
    console.log('3');
    TweenMax.delayedCall(2, test4);
}

function test4()
{
    console.log('4');
    TweenMax.delayedCall(2, test1);
}

test1();
```

http://codepen.io/ronex/pen/yOMWoB